# Loop through excel worksheet and assign variables from contents using SAS

Tags: excel, loops, sas

I have a excel with multiple worksheets and I only need to use a few of them so I did the following to extract just the worksheets that I needed:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT=WORK DATAFILE= 'C:\pathfile'; 
            DBMS=xlsx REPLACE;
     SHEET='seg_schemes'; 
     GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
```

The worksheet "seg_schemes" has multiple variables that I read in with the **GETNAMES=YES** command and there are multiple rows of these variables. The goal is to read each row and assign the excel variables to the declared variables in the SAS script over and over again until each row is processed. The problem I am having is, I am not sure how to loop through each row of the excel worksheet and assign the specific variable for the row. I can not hard code in the number of rows since the data could be added onto the excel file. How would I go about this?

Comment: Show an example of what the excel file looks like, and an example of what the SAS code you'd like to generate from it.

Comment: Hi Anisha, please check it out this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by this `"The goal is to read each row and assign the excel variables to the declared variables in the SAS script over and over again until each row is processed."` You've read in the data into a data set called `work`, so it already exists. What do you want to do with it now? I wouldn't recommend calling it work either, that can get very confusing.